# select rows in one data frame that partially match rows in another data frame

Tags: r, merge, match, apply

I wish to select rows in one data frame, `data.1`, that partially match rows in a second data frame, `keep.these`, to obtain the `desired.result`.  I have found several questions here that match based on one column, but I want to match on three columns: `STATE`, `COUNTY` and `CITY`.  I have come up with three solutions so far, but none seem ideal.

Note that each row contains a unique combination of `STATE`, `COUNTY` and `CITY` in my real data.

When I use `merge` I must re-`order`.  The function `match` seems to work, but I am not familiar with it and do not know if my use of this function is as intended.  The `apply` solution below is clearly too complex.

The `merge` approach would be ideal if I did not have to reorder the result.  Reordering can be time consuming with large data sets.  The `match` approach seems okay if someone can confirm this is a reasonable approach.

Is there a better solution, ideally in base `R`?

```
data.1 <- read.table(text= "
     CITY     COUNTY   STATE        AA
       1          1         1        2
       2          1         1        4
       1          2         1        6
       2          2         1        8
       1          1         2       20
       2          1         2       40
       1          2         2       60
       2          2         2       80
       1          1         3      200
       2          1         3      400
       1          2         3      600
       2          2         3      800
       1          1         4     2000
       2          1         4     4000
       1          2         4     6000
       2          2         4     8000
       1          1         5    20000
       2          1         5    40000
       1          2         5    60000
       2          2         5    80000
", header=TRUE, na.strings=NA)

keep.these <- read.table(text= "
     CITY     COUNTY     STATE      BB
       1          1         2      -10
       2          1         2      -11
       1          2         2      -12
       2          2         2      -13
       1          1         4      -14
       2          1         4      -15
       1          2         4      -16
       2          2         4      -17
", header=TRUE, na.strings=NA)

desired.result <- read.table(text= "
     CITY     COUNTY    STATE       AA
       1          1         2       20
       2          1         2       40
       1          2         2       60
       2          2         2       80
       1          1         4     2000
       2          1         4     4000
       1          2         4     6000
       2          2         4     8000
", header=TRUE, na.strings=NA)

##########

# this works, but I need to reorder

new.data.a <- merge(keep.these[,1:3], data.1, by=c('CITY', 'COUNTY', 'STATE'))

new.data.a <- new.data.a[order(new.data.a$STATE, new.data.a$COUNTY, new.data.a$CITY),]

rownames(desired.result) <- NULL
rownames(new.data.a)     <- NULL

all.equal(desired.result, new.data.a)

##########

# this seems to work, but match is unfamiliar

new.data.2 <- data.1[match(data.1$CITY  , keep.these$CITY  , nomatch=0) & 
                     match(data.1$STATE , keep.these$STATE , nomatch=0) & 
                     match(data.1$COUNTY, keep.these$COUNTY, nomatch=0),]

rownames(desired.result) <- NULL
rownames(new.data.2)     <- NULL

all.equal(desired.result, new.data.2)

##########

# this works, but is too complex

data.1b      <- data.frame(my.group = apply(    data.1[,1:3], 1, paste, collapse = "."),     data.1)
keep.these.b <- data.frame(my.group = apply(keep.these[,1:3], 1, paste, collapse = "."), keep.these)

data.1b <- data.1b[apply(data.1b, 1, function(x) {x[1] %in% keep.these.b$my.group}),]
data.1b <- data.1b[,-1]

rownames(desired.result) <- NULL
rownames(data.1b)        <- NULL

all.equal(desired.result, data.1b)

##########
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a generic solution for this type of problem which is very efficient:

```
data.1.ID <- paste(data.1[,1],data.1[,2],data.1[,3])

keep.these.ID <- paste(keep.these[,1],keep.these[,2],keep.these[,3])

desired.result <- data.1[data.1.ID %in% keep.these.ID,]
```

I have simply created an unique ID for each record, and then searched it.
Note: This will change the row names, and you may want to add the following:

```
row.names(desired.result) <- 1:nrow(desired.result)
```

**EDIT:**

Here is another way to solve the same problem.

If you have a very large data set, say millions of rows, another very efficient solution is using the package `data.table`. It works nearly 50-100 times faster than `merge`, depending on how much data you have.

All you have to do is the following:

```
library(data.table)
```

Step1: Convert `data.frame` to `data.table`, with first three columns as keys.

```
d1 <- data.table(data.1, key=names(data.1)[1:3])
kt <- data.table(keep.these, key=names(keep.these)[1:3])
```

Step2: A merge using `data.table`'s binary search:

```
d1[kt]
```

Note1: The simplicity of execution.
Note2: This will sort the data by key. To avoid that try following:

```
data.1$index <- 1:nrow(data.1)  # Add index to original data
d1 <- data.table(data.1,key=names(data.1)[1:3]) # Step1 as above
kt <- data.table(keep.these,key=names(keep.these)[1:3])  # Step1 as above
d1[kt][order(index)]  # Step2 as above
```

If you want to remove the last two columns (`index`, `BB`), that's straight forward too:

```
d1[kt][order(index)][,-(5:6),with=F] #Remove index
```

Try this with large data sets, and compare the timing with `merge`. It's typically about 50-100 times faster.

To learn more about `data.table`, try:

```
vignette("datatable-intro")
vignette("datatable-faq")
vignette("datatable-timings")
```

Or see it in action:

```
example(data.table)
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you.  Very nice.  This is my `apply` solution with all the `apply` functions removed!

Comment: +1, if you're sticking to data.tables, using `setDT` to modify the data.frame to data.table by reference would be instant (+ no copy - useful on large data).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how this will do in terms of time, compared to reordering, but you can simply add an option to merge to not change the sort.

```
new.data.a <- merge(keep.these[,1:3], data.1, by=c('CITY', 'COUNTY', 'STATE'), sort = FALSE)
rownames(desired.result) <- NULL
rownames(new.data.a)     <- NULL
all.equal(desired.result, new.data.a)
```

Comment: Perfect!  I looked at the `merge` help page, but did not notice that option.