# How to select rows based on the combination of columns from other data frame

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I have a two data frames (`data.1` and `data.2`) with three columns that are present in both (`CITY`, `COUNTY` and `STATE`).

What I want is to filter the first data frame based on values in three columns present in the second data frame (that may have extra, so I need intersection). Although I can produce a working code as here: [select rows in one data frame that partially match rows in another data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145087/select-rows-in-one-data-frame-that-partially-match-rows-in-another-data-frame)

I'd like to have a more generic solution, where names of columns are passed, for example. I know a solution using `left_join` in `dplyr`, but I don't need the extra columns, I just want to filter.

```
data.1 <- read.table(text= "
     CITY     COUNTY   STATE        AA
       1          1         1        2
       2          1         1        4
       1          2         1        6
       2          2         1        8
       1          1         2       20
       2          1         2       40
       1          2         2       60
       2          2         2       80
       1          1         3      200
       2          1         3      400
       1          2         3      600
       2          2         3      800
       1          1         4     2000
       2          1         4     4000
       1          2         4     6000
       2          2         4     8000
       1          1         5    20000
       2          1         5    40000
       1          2         5    60000
       2          2         5    80000
", header=TRUE, na.strings=NA)

data.2 <- read.table(text= "
     CITY     COUNTY     STATE      BB
       1          1         2      -10
       2          1         2      -11
       1          2         2      -12
       2          2         2      -13
       1          1         4      -14
       2          1         4      -15
       1          2         4      -16
       2          2         4      -17
       3          3         4      -18
", header=TRUE, na.strings=NA)

desired.result <- read.table(text= "
     CITY     COUNTY    STATE       AA
       1          1         2       20
       2          1         2       40
       1          2         2       60
       2          2         2       80
       1          1         4     2000
       2          1         4     4000
       1          2         4     6000
       2          2         4     8000
", header=TRUE, na.strings=NA)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use `merge` (or any other `join` method from `dplyr`) and remove extra columns afterwise. For instance `merge(data.1,data.2,all=FALSE)[-5]`.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that I can't answer my own question? The function I was looking for is called `semi_join` from `dplyr` package. I would think of keeping the question for the sake of those new to table joins that learn terminology with the hep of SO. :)